# set_time_limit() not success in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

helloo..

I have a problem when use curl function in codeigniter 4. I want to upload a big data to server but when run the aplication i get error :

Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

I have added set_time_limit(3600) but still error.

```
public function uploadDataJabs()
{
  
    $client = \Config\Services::curlrequest();
    set_time_limit(3600);   
            
    }
```

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the time out happening? the PHP script sending the data or the server receiving the data?

Comment: my server sending the data, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `set_time_limit(0);` means the script can run forever (however this is not recommended). You can check the [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) manual for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

Example (in Codeigniter 4):

```
$client = \Config\Services::curlrequest();

$bodyJSON = "{'your_json_here'}";
$yourURL = 'https://your.url.here';

$response = $client->setBody($bodyJSON )->request('POST', $yourURL, [
     'headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     ],
     'connect_timeout' => (60 * 4), // in seconds 60 = 1 minute, 0 = off
     'timeout' => (60 * 4) // in seconds 60 = 1 minute, 0 = off
]);

$body = $response->getBody();
```